# coinList.maps is not a function error how do I convert a object to a array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
var NumberFormat = require("react-number-format");

export default class Coinlist extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      coinList: [],
      isLoaded: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
      "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist&api_key="
    )
      .then(res => res.json)
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          coinList: json
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    var { isLoaded, coinList } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="Coinlist">
          <ul>
            {coinList.maps(coins => (
              <li key={coins.Name}>{coins.Id}</li>
            ))}
            ;
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I have a problem with "TypeError: coinList.maps is not a function" I need to convert the object coinList to a array but can't figure out how. I would be really grateful if someone could help me with this issue. I'm really new to this all

Comment: Can you post the value of `coinList` as well so that we may help

Comment: **Edit your question** to insert the requested data. Screenshots are not accepted here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `coinList.Data.BTC.Name` and `coinList.Data.BTC.Id` to map it to UI.

If you want all the coins, then try the code below.

```
const coinDetails = Object.values(coinList.Data);
coinDetails.forEach(cd => console.log(cd.Name + ' ' + cd.Id));
```

The above code will give you values in console. I hope that will help you to get the values and use it in UI.

Comment: Hey I tryed it and it doesn't seem to work I still get the error "TypeError: coinList.maps is not a function"

Comment: coinList will not have map. Check how I have used coinList. coinList is having a key named `Data` which I am extracting and getting all the values from the JSON referring to `coinList.Data`. Those values will be in array which will have .map function.